# Watermark via package 'draftwatermark' is not showing on page

Tags: watermark

I'm trying to add a watermark to my paper, simply by adding a

```
 \usepackage{draftwatermark}
```

But the watermark doesn't appear to be showing up?

On closer inspection, it's there, but offset from the page, so it only just shows in one corner.

Any ideas? I'm using a journal specific style class (MNRAS / `mn2e.cls`).

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{mn2e}
\usepackage{draftcopy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal working example, please?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a MWE (and an image of the resulting document) illustrating the problem mentioned; I hope it's OK.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out eventually. According to the documentation,  `draftwatermark`

> also assumes that \paperwidth and \paperheight are set correctly.

I suspected the journal class file might be doing something weird. Turns out you can enforce the standard page size by including

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

*after* you set up the document with `mn2e`.

Here's a fixed MWE, with some `draftwatermark` options for good measure:

```
\documentclass{mn2e}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkScale{5}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-11]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

or set them explicitly

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{height=11truein,width=8.5truein}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}\SetWatermarkText{{\ifnum\value{page}>12 Too long \else\fi}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you expand your answer by providing a complete example that users may directly paste and compile? See as example TimS's answer. It also makes clear to new users where your proposed solution has to be put in the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Also rewrite your answer: For me it is not immediately clear what you refer to, because on with my setting your answer appears in the moment before the other one. Something like “In addition to answer of TimS. You can also set papersize explicitly …”