# Image like watermark

Tags: graphics, watermark

Is there any package to insert an image (like a watermark) giving the X and Y coordinates, although then goes over the text?

Comment: I think there is a package for watermarks, but there are also ways of placing things at (x,y) on page with other text: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73243/watermark-via-package-draftwatermark-is-not-showing-on-page and others... search the site for "watermark"

Comment: `eso-pic` with absolute positioning? You can place a grid over the page when working to help with coordinate placement (and then obviously get rid of the grid when done). I think this is a two file solution though. (I've used it to fill in PDF forms which are not created as fillable.)

Comment: `xwatermark` might be helpful (allows multiple watermarks over or under text. `xpos` and `ypos` specify coordinates and you can customise things in various ways. [Untested - I've never used this package and you've not supplied an MWE so it is hard to say more.] If you are filling 'holes' with graphics, though, I wonder if this is really the best approach. A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would make it a lot easier to help!

Answer (score 3):

I used the `background` package to watermark versions of a document with `\today`. It uses tikz nodes which allows a lot of customizations but has useful default values so you don't have to care:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{cc.png}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good idea, but I want to put the image with X,Y coordinates. It's possible? My problem is this: in some cases I have a blank speace to fill with image. For this I think that the coordinates are the solution...

Comment: I create an image : http://imgur.com/dRgOdJx. Is possible insert an images on the square red boxes with coordinates?

Comment: While it is possible to specify the position in absolute values from the top left corner `position={x,y},scale=1` (use negative y values), the package is more useful for one background element per page. At least I couldn't find an option to add multiple background elements.

Comment: I have posted another answer with the multiple images requirement in mind. As an alternative approach, I thought it justifies the formulation of an additional answer instead of enhancing this one.

Answer (score 3):

A simplified version from [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169836/60603) to [the question already linked by Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808), combined with the mechanisms of the `background` package (using the `everypage` hooks to draw under the text) could solve your need for (1.) absolute positioning of (2.) multiple images as (3.) watermarks.

Code and example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcommand*{\AbsolutePosition}[3]{%
    % #1 = x (from south west corner of page
    % #2 = y
    % #3 = content
    \AddThispageHook{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \draw (current page.south west) ++(#1,#2) node {#3};%
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\AbsolutePosition{5.0cm}{6.0cm}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{cc.png} (5,6)}
\AbsolutePosition{10.0cm}{12.0cm}{\includegraphics[scale=2]{cc.png} (10,12)}
\AbsolutePosition{10.0cm}{17.0cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{cc.png}(10,17)}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very good! Here it is! And... If I have two pages in document? With coordinates, can I put different images on different pages?

Comment: The image will be on the same page as the surrounding text.

Comment: You're right, maybe pretend too. I'm using the songs latex package that creates a layout with double column and double page. Anyway I just so. Thank you.