# watermark behind image

Tags: watermark

i used code from topic: [Image like watermark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208075/image-like-watermark)

Minimal Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,8pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\Placing}[3]{%
  % #1 = x (from south west corner of page
  % #2 = y
  % #3 = content
  \AddThispageHook{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \draw (current page.south west) ++(#1,#2) node {#3};%
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\Placing{4.8cm}{22.0cm}{\includegraphics[height=3cm,angle=45]{example-image-c}}
  \lipsum[4]

  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}

 \lipsum[4]
\Placing{7.8cm}{17.0cm}{\includegraphics[height=3cm,angle=45]{example-image-b}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But watermark (image B, C) behind image A.

How can i put watermark (B,C) over image A?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your watermarks should be behind the text in the background. So if they should be over image A, image A must go in the background too (this needs two compilations):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,8pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum,zref-savepos}
\newcommand*{\Placing}[3]{%
  % #1 = x (from south west corner of page
  % #2 = y
  % #3 = content
  \AddThispageHook{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \draw (current page.south west) ++(#1,#2) node {#3};%
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\AddThispageHook{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \draw (current page.south west) ++(\zposx{picture}sp,\zposy{picture}sp) 
          node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}};%
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\Placing{4.8cm}{22.0cm}{\includegraphics[height=3cm,angle=45]{example-image-c}}


\Placing{4.8cm}{22.0cm}{\includegraphics[height=3cm,angle=45]{example-image-c}}
  \lipsum[4]

  \centering
  \leavevmode\zsavepos{picture}\phantom{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}

 \lipsum[4]
\Placing{7.8cm}{17.0cm}{\includegraphics[height=3cm,angle=45]{example-image-b}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX I randomly write to, too, two - in 1 of 3 it should be okay ;-)

Comment: I imagined :), I didn't correct by myself beacause I supposed you were editing, too